# Polymorphic relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship

Please, Help me!

I have User model and migration: `id, login, password`.

3 roles and models (`Admin`, `Teacher`, `Student`) and here more information about user. And user can get several roles (he can be admin and teacher)
And one polymorphic model Role with columns:

```
user_id
roleable_id
roleable_type
```

For example, `User::find(1)->roles;`

And i'd like that result shows two model (admin and teacher).
Pleasee, help me))

Comment: Are Admin, Teacher and Student user models or just roles?

Comment: In User stores only login and password. After registration he can choose roles: Admin, Teacher and Student. And write more information about him. But he can be admin and teacher(one to many). For that, I need polymorphic model Role with columns user_id - 1(from User model), roleable_id - 1 (from Admin model), roleable_type - App\Admin.  next row: user_id - 1, roleable_id - 1, roleable_type - App\Teacher etc.

Comment: So no, Admin, Teacher and Student are not user models. I'm just not understanding why your roles need to be set up as a polymorphic...whats the difference between role_id 1 and role_id 2 for an admin?

Comment: yes, Admin, Teacher and Student are separate models

Answer (score 0):

You could try to eager load the models by using this in your User model https://gist.github.com/thisdotvoid/3022fee8afa53e45a6b89da3f16b3815. Add the required morph functions and then add three functions to the user model similar to this one (change the name and the model name accordingly):

```
public function admin()
{
    return BelongsToMorph::build($this, 'App\Admin', 'rolable');
}
```

Then create a mutator function like

```
function getRolesAttribute()
{
  $roles = new Collection();

  $roleNames = ['admin', 'teacher', 'student'];

  foreach ($roleNames as $role) {

     $hasRole = $this->{$role};

     if ($hasRole) {
       $roles->push($role);
     }

  }

  return $roles;
}
```